# How to use regex in file IO?

Tags: perl

**In Perl**
I am trying to find a file(string) which is in array(contains file names) inside one directory. But in that directory the file is there along with some number. so it is not finding that file.

File name in array is like : template_to_do,
Exact name inside directory is like :  template_to_do.12345

I used this code :

```
$regr = path to directory if(-e "$regr/$_")
```

It's not picking that file.
I tried as reg exp as shown below but it also didn't work out.

```
if(-e "m[$regr\/$_.\d*]")
```

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: `In Perl` - why tag as java?

Answer (score 1):

`-e` expects a file name, not a regular expression. You haven't shown what's inside `$_`, so we can't comment what's wrong with the first command.

You can use [glob](http://p3rl.org/glob) to expand a pattern (switch to `File::Glob::bsd_glob` if $regr can contain whitespace):

```
for (@array) {
    my @files = glob "$regr/$_.*";
    print "Found @files";
}
```

You can use [grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) to filter the names by a regex:

```
if (my @files = grep /\.[0-9]+$/, glob "$regr/$_.*") {
    print "Found @files.\n" if -e $files[0];
}
```